# Java: SELECT query in INNER JOIN

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

Following SQL query works perfectly fine in Postgres. It returns all latest trainings of a given exercise.

```
SELECT th.id, th.date, th.exercise_id
FROM Training th
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT exercise_id, MAX(date) AS maxdate
  FROM Training
  GROUP BY exercise_id
  ) AS tm ON tm.exercise_id = th.exercise_id AND th.date = tm.maxdate
```

---

The problem is that Java JPA fails with

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException unexpected token: (`

after the `INNER JOIN` for the following code example.

```
String queryString = "SELECT th FROM TrainingHistory th INNER JOIN ( SELECT tm.exercise, MAX(date) as maxdate FROM TrainingHistory group by exercise ) AS tm on (tm.exercise = th.exercise AND th.date = tm.maxdate) WHERE th.accountId = 0";
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you create your query as native (`em.createNativeQuery` instead of `em.createQuery`)?

Comment: Thank you @BorLaze. That made this error go away, but other problems raised, like `PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC`. I think I should try to use CriteriaBuilder somehow to solve this SQL. Please answer this question and I will mark it as solution.